# Query astropy or skyfield to get planets positions into a QGIS layer

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I want to have a layer in QGIS where I give a date/time input and it will query astropy to get the sun, moon and planets position at that specific moment.

https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/coordinates/solarsystem.html
https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/

Comment: That is nice. But what is your question?

Comment: how do I do it?

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I am a bit lost on this. I feel that a little bit of code would do the job, but I don't know where to start... I looked at enmap-box that is a plugin that uses astropy, but for a completely different purpose, so I got nowhere...  should i install astropy inside qgis? or run it from the python console?